# How to get unmodified json data for column of datatable

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

I am working on a project using Laravel and yajrabix/laravel-datatables. I am having an issue when trying to access a column using columndefs. The column is supposed to be JSON data. Nothing is working to work with the data in that column. Is there a way to send the data unmodified for that column?

Bottom line, I would like to be able to access the data from the json stored in the results column. No matter what I do, it doesnt work.

Here is the code in my blade view. Everything else works on the datatable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var table = $('.table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false,
                ajax: "/admin/logs/datatable/lookup-ip",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'ip_address', name: 'ip_address'},
                    {data: 'results', name: 'results'},
                    {data: 'created_by', name: 'created_by'},
                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: "_all",
                        className: 'nk-tb-col tb-col-mb'
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 2,
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return 'ISP: ' + data.ip;
                        }
                    }
                ],
            });

        });
    </script>
```

This is the function in the controller serving the datatable.

```
    public function datatable($log)
    {
        switch($log)
        {
            case 'activity':
                $table = config('activitylog.table_name');
                break;
            case 'lookup-ip':
                $table = IPLookup::getModel()->getTable();
                break;
            case 'lookup-phone':
                $table = PhoneLookup::getModel()->getTable();
                break;
        }

        $query = DB::table($table);
        return DataTables::of($query)->toJson();
    }
```

This is the data that is stored in the database.

```
{"ip": "8.8.8.8", "asn": "AS15169", "isp": "Google LLC", "org": "Google LLC", "city": "Ashburn", "type": "IPv4", "region": "Virginia", "country": "United States", "success": true, "currency": "US Dollar", "latitude": "39.0437567", "timezone": "America/New_York", "continent": "North America", "longitude": "-77.4874416", "country_code": "US", "country_flag": "https://cdn.ipwhois.io/flags/us.svg", "timezone_gmt": "GMT -5:00", "country_phone": "+1", "currency_code": "USD", "timezone_name": "Eastern Standard Time", "continent_code": "NA", "currency_rates": "1", "country_capital": "Washington", "currency_plural": "US dollars", "currency_symbol": "$", "completed_requests": 29, "country_neighbours": "CA,MX,CU", "timezone_dstOffset": "0", "timezone_gmtOffset": "-18000"}
```

The model of the IP log has casts setup.

```
    protected $casts = [
        'results' => 'array',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it figures after posting the question... I figure it out.

According to yajrabox:
By default, Laravel DataTables protects us from XSS attack by escaping all our outputs. In cases where you want to render an html content, please use rawColumns api.

So I modified the code in the controller returning the datatable and now it works as expected and I can parse the JSON and use it as an object in javascript.

```
 return DataTables::of($query)
        ->rawColumns(['results'])
        ->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've notice is that the data stored on your database, according to your example, isn't wrapped into the array brackets (`[ ]`) and you're using a cast on the Module. That could be the cause of the problem.

Try going to your database and manually wrapping your JSON on array brackets and give it a shot!

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. yajrabox is just a package for laravel that works with https://datatables.net/

I think that the data is being manipulated or changed by the yajrabox package. When I use the API to retrieve the data without the package the JSON data returns fine. But when I use the package, it returns it with these weird quotes and I think that is messing it up. ""results":"[{&quot;ip&quot;: &quot;8.8.8.8&quot;, &quot;asn